# Concatenate multiple files in add_custom_command

Tags: cmake, xsd

We have applications that need to ship with an .xsd file that is composed of just several other .xsd files concatenated together. The source list for concatenation can be derived by walking all the library dependencies and examining a property on it.

What I ended up with was a function that an application's CMakeLists.txt can just invoke, which will "do the right thing":

```
function(make_config_xsd)
    set(xsd_config ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.xsd)

    # build up a list of config files that are going to be concatenated
    set(config_list ${appcommon_SOURCE_DIR}/config/common.xsd)

    # iterate over the library dependencies and pull out config_file properties
    get_target_property(libraries ${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_LIBRARIES)
    foreach(lib ${libraries})
        get_target_property(conf ${lib} config_file)
        if(conf)
            list(APPEND config_list ${conf})
        endif()
    endforeach()

    # finally, add the app specific one last
    list(APPEND config_list ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config/config.xsd)

    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${xsd_config}
        COMMAND echo \"<?xml version=\\"1.0\\"?><xs:schema xmlns:xs=\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\\">\" > ${xsd_config}
        COMMAND cat ${config_list} >> ${xsd_config}
        COMMAND echo \"</xs:schema>\" >> ${xsd_config}
        DEPENDS "${config_list}")

    add_custom_target(generate-config DEPENDS ${xsd_config})
    add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} generate-config)
endfunction()
```

This *appears* to work. But I'm not sure if it is actually the "Right Way" to go about solving this problem, and having a fake `add_custom_target()` that just depends on the output from `add_custom_command()` just so that I can do `add_dependencies()` doesn't seem right either. Is there a more direct way to do a dependency on a generated file like this?

Comment: If other custom command or custom target depends on your config file, no needs to create additional custom target. In case of library or executable, dependency on a file may be specified by adding the file to list of source files.

Comment: 1. what about add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD ....) ?

2. prefer to use COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E, unfortunately there isn't any cat concat

3. You could use FILE(READ ...) FILE(WRITE) cf. [this post on cmake mailing list](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-July/038028.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997207/concatenate-multiple-files-in-add-custom-command#comment82965626_47997207) points out, just add the generate config file to the target's list of sources.

That is, replace:

```
add_custom_target(generate-config DEPENDS ${xsd_config})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} generate-config)
```

with just:

```
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} ${xsd_config})
```